# Select specific columns from Cassandra based on their name

Tags: cassandra

I have a cassandra database in which columns can be added or removed based on the application need. The column names start with the prefix `RSSI`. I was wondering if it is possible to select all columns where the column name is like `%RSSI%`. In MYSQL you can do something like `select count(*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE table_name ='MACTrain' AND column_name LIKE '%RSSI%'`. Is it possible in cassandra ? If not what can be a solution to select columns based on a specific wildcard.

Answer (score 2):

You can obtain the columns metadata of a table by querying the `system` keyspace:

```
select * from system.schema_columns 
where keyspace_name = 'yourks' and columnfamily_name = 'yourtable';
```

For Cassandra v3.0 and above, you can use the new `system_schema` keyspace:

```
select * from system_schema.columns 
where keyspace_name = 'yourks' and table_name = 'yourtable';
```